# GNS3 - Connected to Dynamips VM “R1” (ID 1, type c3600) - Console port Press ENTER to get the prompt

Tags: gns3

I am using windows 10 and I tried to open router console in gns3 and get this massage in console window(Connected to Dynamips VM "R1" (ID 1, type c3600) - Console port Press ENTER to get the prompt) when I pressed enter nothing is happen. no error no anything. I installed versions (GNS 0.8.6 , 1.3.13 , 1.4.6 and the last version) and used a lot of images like (3640 and c3725-advipservicesk9-mz.124-18) but the same issue is still.
Is anyone faces this issue before ?????

Comment: Is your terminal application set to `9600 8 N 1`?

Comment: I can't get what you mean exactly for (terminal application). but I am using default terminal of GNS3 and I don't know  what it is set to .

Comment: The baud rate seems fine, you also need to deactivate flow control (no Xon/Xoff nor RTS/CTS).

Comment: But how to deactivate flow control ???

Comment: @KarimYousry There are a lot of other great console programs to use with configuring your network equipment. Personally i use TeraTerm, which today is free. With that you can specifically select to deactivate flow control.

Comment: @KarimYousry so was the issue flow control any further updates? I tried to recreate your issue this morning, however testing was done with GNS3 2.1.1 which is the latest and c3620-a3jk9s-mz.122-26c.bin, pretty much everything done with default settings and worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,It is working now  when I avoided default RAM editing of IOS router just let default RAM and it will work but I can't know why.Thanks DRP 
and all for helping.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the questions doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that accepting the default RAM entry will solve this issue.  I was clicking finish without an idle-pc value found.  After accepting the default RAM, the wizard found an idle-pc value, and then I was able to finally connect via putty.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can setting RAM is 256MB or 512MB on C7200

Comment: Please elaborate your answer somewhat. As it is, we can't tell if you're simply guessing or whether there's been some thought.